# Not able to following links in Scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm beginning now with Scrapy, and I got how to take the content I wanted from a sport page (name and team of a soccer player), but I need to follow the links searching for more teams, every team page have a link to players page, the structure of website link is :

team page: http://esporte.uol.com.br/futebol/clubes/vitoria/
players page: http://esporte.uol.com.br/futebol/clubes/vitoria/jogadores/

I've read some Scrapy tutorials and I'm thinking the team pages I have to follow links and don't parse nothing, and the players page I have to no-follow and parse the players, I don't know if I'm right with this idea and wrong with the syntax, of if my idea of follow is wrong, any help is welcome.

here is my code:

```
class MoneyballSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "moneyball"
    allowed_domains = ["esporte.uol.com.br", "click.uol.com.br", "uol.com.br"]
    start_urls = ["http://esporte.uol.com.br/futebol/clubes/vitoria/jogadores/"]

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'.*futebol/clubes/.*/', ), deny=(r'.*futebol/clubes/.*/jogadores/', )), follow = True),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'.*futebol/clubes/.*/jogadores/', )), callback='parse', follow = True),
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        jogadores = hxs.select('//div[@id="jogadores"]/div/ul/li')
        items = []
        for jogador in jogadores:
            item = JogadorItem()
            item['nome'] = jogador.select('h5/a/text()').extract()
            item['time'] = hxs.select('//div[@class="header clube"]/h1/a/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
            print item['nome'], item['time']
        return items
```

Comment: Well, does it work or doesn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, since you need to follow an extract links, you need a [CrawlSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) instead of a `BaseSpider`. Then, you need to define two rules: one for players with a callback, and one for teams without, to follow. Also, you should start with a URL with list of teams, like http://esporte.uol.com.br/futebol. Here's a complete spider, that returns players from different teams:

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class JogadorItem(Item):
    nome = Field()
    time = Field()


class MoneyballSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "moneyball"
    allowed_domains = ["esporte.uol.com.br", "click.uol.com.br", "uol.com.br"]
    start_urls = ["http://esporte.uol.com.br/futebol"]

    rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'.*futebol/clubes/.*?/jogadores/', )), callback='parse_players', follow=True),
             Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'.*futebol/clubes/.*', )), follow=True),)

    def parse_players(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        jogadores = hxs.select('//div[@id="jogadores"]/div/ul/li')
        items = []
        for jogador in jogadores:
            item = JogadorItem()
            item['nome'] = jogador.select('h5/a/text()').extract()
            item['time'] = hxs.select('//div[@class="header clube"]/h1/a/text()').extract()
            items.append(item)
            print item['nome'], item['time']
        return items
```

Quote from the output:

```
...
[u'Silva'] [u'Vila Nova-GO']
[u'Luizinho'] [u'Vila Nova-GO']
...
[u'Michel'] [u'Guarani']
[u'Wellyson'] [u'Guarani']
...
```

This is just hint for you to continue working on the spider, you'll need to tweak the spider further: choose an appropriate start URL depending on your needs etc.

Hope that helps.